# Identify Built-in objects with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

Is anyone aware of any means to test if a View, Table or Filter is part of the 'Built-in' set?

I can't see nor find any obvious way of doing this so will build some collections that hold the names of these items so that i can avoid these in code, but it feels like there should be a property that identifies these..............

Answer (score 0):

There is no "built-in" property.

Furthermore, Views, Tables, and Filters can be modified and/or deleted by the user so even if you find a view called "Gantt Chart" it may not resemble the standard (default) view. You can build a list of view names, but don't count on one in a user's file being the same as in any other file.

Comment: I felt that was probably the case, however MS Project itself identifies 'Built-in' Views, Tables etc, in the pull downs.  I was building a bulk-update feature for my own Views etc, and was looking for an easy way to specifically identify items that I, initially, would not want to re-name.  Not a problem just some extra Collections to build.